# how to run simple program in react-native but getting error

Tags: android, react-native

[image: error while app run]starting learning of react-native but the first program was not run in the device. 
any help to run this program.

```
  import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
  import { Alert,View } from 'react-native';  

   const App = () => {
   return (
    alert("Hello ")
    );
    }

  export default App;
```

above my app.js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your return should contain a react component..alert is not a component it's a function...
use like this to show alert....

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import { Alert,View } from 'react-native';  

 const App = () => {
 return (
  <View> 
    {Alert.alert("title ","message")}
  </View>
     );
   }

   export default App;
```